# From where Rails take their DateTime.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Recently I wanted to change `updated_at` column of a post, but it's not that simple!

Nevertheless, server time is 12:06 and when I use console (irb) it is 12:06 
Also tried:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.zone.to_s
=> "(GMT+03:00) Moscow"
```

Still when I do :

```
post.update!(updated_at: DateTime.now)
=> true
```

And if I retrieve the record, the result is "2018-10-29 09:06:47"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what time zone set in your application.rb file ?

Comment: Slightly dated, but still good article on time in Rails: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones

Comment: @ Vishal     config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Comment: @jdno Nice article! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`DateTime.current`](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/current/class) - that will get the zoned time if your app is operating in one.

From the docs:

> Returns Time.zone.now.to_datetime when Time.zone or config.time_zone are set, otherwise returns Time.now.to_datetime.

Basically, `Time.zone` should reflect `DateTime.current` if you're working with a time zone, while `Time.now` and `DateTime.now` will ignore any zone. The method's source is quite self explanatory here:

```
def current
  ::Time.zone ? ::Time.zone.now.to_datetime : ::Time.now.to_datetime
end
```

Hope that helps - give me a shout if you've any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so arrogant to consider `now` method as just a shorter alias for `current`! Shame on me!

Comment: You're welcome, though I'd disagree on any arrogance here - it's a straightforward mistake to make, and one I tripped over a few weeks ago myself :)